# Scraping Python Script: Looping and updating output

Tags: python, loops, feed

So I have this python script. Right now, I run the script and it gives me an output file in CSV.

What I want: When it finishes to restart and to check for changes to those output values (not refresh the output file when it restarts and erase all the previously collected data)

As well, it takes about 3 seconds per line of data to get retrieved. Does anyone know how I can get it going fast to handle large data sets?

```
import urllib2,re,urllib,urlparse,csv,sys,time,threading,codecs
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def extract(url):
    try:
        sys.stdout.write('0')
        global file
        page = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()

        soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')

        product = soup.find("div", {"class": "js-product-price"})
        price = product.findNext('div',{'class':'js-price-display'}).getText().strip()
        oos = product.findNext('p', attrs={'class': "price-oos"})

        if oos is None:
            oos = 'In Stock'
        else:
            oos = oos.getText()

        val = url + "," + price + "," + oos + "," + time.ctime() + '\n'
        ifile.write(val)
        sys.stdout.write('1')
    except Exception as e:
        print e
        #pass
    return

ifile = open('output.csv', "a", 0)
ifile.write('URL' + "," + 'Price' + "," + 'Stock' + "," + "Time" + '\n')
inputs = csv.reader(open('input.csv'))
#inputs = csv.reader(codecs.open('input.csv', 'rU', 'utf-16'))
for i in inputs:
    extract(i[0])
ifile.close()
print("finished")
```

Comment: Can anyone help me figure this out?

Comment: Stackoverflow is about questions you have tried to find an answer for and not about someone writing your program for you. Show us what you have tried so far to reach your "What I want" result.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply. I had been trying lots of things, luckily today I finally figured it out. Next time i'll remember to post what I tried, won't forget again. Thanks!